# Crontab and python project

Tags: cron, python-3.9, raspberry-pi-os

I have a simple python project to water my plants, it works with a Raspberry and RaspberryPi os lite.
In the project I have a package named `app` with a `__main__.py` to launch it, I just type `python -m app` in the terminal and it works fine.
I tried to make a crontab with `* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/djangeau/app`
Nothing happens, whereas if I launch a simple python test script it does.
The cron log gives me that error : 'No MTA installed, discarding output' , not sure this is useful to solve the problem.
I hope I was clear enough. Thank you for your answers. Vincent

Answer (score 0):

MTA is for mailing purposes as cron sends email whereas ubuntu doesn't have MTA. Below is the link for a better understanding:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out:

For exemple that command in bash : `python -m app`
is equivalent to this one for a crontab :
`* * * * * cd /home/pi/djangeau && /usr/bin/python -m app`

Just replace the correct path and stars by the schedule you want